# Changing color of heatmap in R

Tags: r, dictionary, heat

I have a file that contains the cluster results. I created a heatmap  in R by the following code.How to change the color of heatmap to red and green

```
nba <- read.csv("E:/clus.arff", sep=",")
nba_heatmap <- heatmap(nba_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `cm.color` palette which is a cyan-purple palette.

You can create your own palette for instance using RColorBrewer.

RColorBrewer provides a red-yellow-green palette you can use

```
library(RColorBrewer)
pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdYlGn"))(100)
```

`brewer.pal` loads the palette (the palette has 11 colors, we're gonna use them all) and then `colorRampPalette` interpolates it to 100 colors.

Alternatively you can define your own colors:

```
redgreen <- c("red", "green") 
pal <- colorRampPalette(redgreen)(100)
```

After creating the palette just use it as the `col` parameter to `heatmap`.